# Flask-Frozen: How to generate a 404 page?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to generate a 404 page for my Flask-Frozen application. Currently, this is my only error-handling logic in views.py

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

Apparently, that isn't enough code to do the trick, any suggestions?

Comment: please explain it properly for better answers..

Answer (score 4):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Add a call to [`freezer.register_generator`](http://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/#flask_frozen.Freezer.register_generator) that returns at least one URL that will result in your 404 page:

   ```
   @freezer.register_generator
   def error_handlers():
       yield "/404"
   ```
2. Setup your web server to respond to 404 errors with your static page (the example is for Apache):

   ```
   ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `Frozen-Flask` which freezes the site to serve it statically.
There's no way to handle static pages in a static site unless you configure your webserver to serve a specific page in case of error.